# Azure: Service principal user best practice with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am a bit confused about how we should be using the Service Principle user when we are managing our infrastructure on Azure using Terraform.

For example, is it recommended to have a single SP for the whole team to share? or would we need to setup an SP for each user?

If its SP per user, that causes issues for some resources such as key vaults which would have been provisioned with one SP user and so the access policy have been defined for that user, whilst another person in the team with a different SP would not have access to modify that vault from their laptop.

Not sure if my question is clear enough but failing to find concrete details around these scenarios.

Much apprecated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A service principal should be used when you have a *service* (non-human) performing an operation.  In this scenario, for example, Terraform would use a service principal to provision your infrastructure as part of a CI/CD pipeline.

Service principals (in any environment) are generally configured with *least privilege*.  The reason for this is that a service principal is intended to be used for a single and very specific purpose, such as invoking Terraform to provision your environment.  So, your service principal may have permissions to read a specific set of secrets from Azure Key Vault that are used to provision resources in a specific resource group (or set of resource groups).  That's it.

Compare this with a user account, such as what you use to do your work.  You may have access to multiple Azure subscriptions, can provision resources anywhere you want, delete resources, configure access to resources, and more.

A primary reason for using a service principal comes down to security.  Using the example above, if the service principal's credentials (client id and secret) were compromised, then the only thing one could do with those credentials is read a secret from key vault and provision resources in a specific resource group.

The docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_certificate.html#setting-up-an-application-and-service-principal) demonstrate giving a service principal contributor permissions to an entire subscription.  This is less restrictive than the example I gave above.  However, I suspect it is assuming another best practice, which is, your dev/test environment should use a different Azure subscription than your production and other environments.  So, while the service principal has full Contributor permissions to a subscription dedicated to dev/test, it still does not have access to other subscriptions the organization has nor can it be used to configure *access* to resources in the subscription.

Comment: Thanks Rick, you have made a few things clear to. The way we have setup is we have separate subscriptions for int, stg, prod and dev

Comment: One thing I am still unclear about is whether it would be advisable to use a single principal user within the same team or is this against the norms, because we all run terraform from our laptops not from a central location,

Comment: If you're all running from your local machine, then just authenticate using your individual user credentials.  Your laptop is not a "shared environment".  Your co-worker's laptops are not "shared environments".  So, the service principal doesn't apply here.  Again, this is applicable if you had a CI/CD pipeline whereby Terraform was invoked by an automated service (non-human), in which case, you would want to configure the service to use a service principal.

Comment: One more thing.... suppose you created a service principal for your group.  Now you have to tell everyone the client ID and secret to use. So, everyone has to remember these extra credentials - that's bad.  Plus, there's nothing keeping you or others on your team from just ignoring it and using their own user credentials to authenticate and invoke Terraform.  Going back to my first statement - A service principal should be used when you have a **service** performing an operation.

Comment: The annoying thing currently is that in some terraform scripts we have to pass the SP creds to bring up the resource and if we provision the resource with one SP( say mine) and another team member wants to then update that resource using their own SP, things starts to break and Azure permissions errors starts to appear. Hence why we are thinking of using a single SP.  To give you an example, creating a Vault involves passing SP creds to the resource

Comment: Is KeyVault the only resource you run into that scenario?  Key Vaults are a "special" resource and should take on a different management life-cycle than other resources for a solution such as virtual machines, databases, etc.  For example, you should create a key vault one time, in a different resource group, and with limited access (for example, maybe just you and one other person).  Then, the rest of your team uses the key vault to retrieve secrets/keys they need using URI's that **you** give them.

Comment: Key vault is not only the only resources where I have to pass the client secret to, there is also the Azure container Service that require the SP details to be passed to in order to make it work. The way we are designing our infra is each part of the stack would have its own key vault that would be there only for the life time of that stack, so if we bring down the stack, the vault is destroyed as well. Unlike what you are suggesting which is a single vault for the whole environment?

Comment: Correct.  Key Vaults would typically have a different management lifecycle than the solution(s) that depend on them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a model I recommend.  We've mostly implemented it at my company (tech team of around 40 people or so, including infrastructure and devs) and it's been working well.

1. prod subscriptions are separated from dev and test (as @RickRainey suggested).
2. prod is locked down so only the "Deployer" Service Principal (SP) can make changes (and a few Infrastructure Admins in case of emergencies).  The Deployer SP runs terraform via our deployment pipeline (TeamCity in our case).
3. developers have Contributor access to the dev environment, where they're free to experiment and test infrastructure changes.  They do this using their own personal accounts, not an SP (shout out again to @RickRainey).
4. anyone can promote terraform changes to prod, but it has to be via a github Pull Request (PR), approved by an Infrastructure Team member, and applied by the Deployer SP via the deployment pipeline.

This accomplishes several goals:
a) least privileges (prod is locked down),
b) change approval,
c) developer freedom in dev environment,
d) transparency and accessibility of prod environment (because anyone can view the terraform and create PRs).

There are some obvious challenges to getting this all air-tight (e.g., how to protect the SP's credentials in the deployment pipeline), but nothing a smart team can't figure out.